# How to close a specific window with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I open a window with jQuery. Then I want to close it but window.close or nameOfTheWindow.close does not work. How should I do it?

I have the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/D99Gk/2/

HTML:

```
<a class="open" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"> open window 1 </a>
<br><br>    
<a class="close" href="#"> close window 1</a>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
 //I give the window the name window1 and I open it:
    $('.open').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open("","window1","width=400, height=400");
    });

    $('.close').click(function(){
        // I tried and does not work:
        // window.close();
        // window1.close();
    });
})
```

Comment: you can't and that's the answer, but if I try to put that in an answer, I'm sure to be downvoted ;)

Comment: You need to save the reference returned from `window.open()`, which allows you to access that "window's" object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(function(){    
    var popup;
    $('.open').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        popup = window.open("","window1","width=400, height=400");
    });

    $('.close').click(function(){
        if(popup) popup.close();
    });
});
```

### DEMO

Comment: The `if` is a nice touch.

Comment: I do not understand why the conditional? If the window is not open and you click the close window, nothing happens

Comment: @Nrc Check your console, there is error if not using the `if` check because `undefined` hasn't got a close() method

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){    
    var winref;

    $('.open').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        winref = window.open("","window1","width=400, height=400");
    });

    $('.close').click(function(){
        winref.close();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D99Gk/3/

Note: As A. Wolff does, you should check if `winref`:

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    if (winref) winref.close();
});
```

This is to prevent an error from first clicking the close link before `winref` exists, or after it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){    
var wi = null;
    $('.open').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        wi = window.open("","window1","width=400, height=400");
    });

    $('.close').click(function(){
        wi.close();     
    });
})
```

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D99Gk/4/)</kbd>**